# IntelliJ Ctrl-Click on method and autocompletion in HTML doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea

I've started using IntelliJ for angular2 development recently but there seem to be a bug. I know from WebStorm that if I have following html:

```
<button (click)="onHaveClicked()">Button</button>
```

I should be able to jump to the method implementation in my typescript file using ctrl-click. But this shortcut isn't working at all. I've tried multiple different files.

Also autocompletion in html doesnt work at all. It's showing no angular attributes like `ngFor` etc. Angular2 is of course installed.

Was somebody with the same problem able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ doesn't come with Angular support built in. You can however enable it by installing the plugin. Settings -> Plugins -> Install Jetbrains Plugin -> Search for Angular.

This is a general thing with IntelliJ and the other editors. The specialized editors (like PhpStorm and WebStorm) comes with what you need for that editor by default. IntelliJ, which is more general, it often has to be installed manually.

Comment: I have it installed.